# Adding a Extra Field for the next reference

Tags: java, reference, field

I am trying to modify this class to include a extra field for the next reference. Any ideas?

```
 package project2;

 public interface Entry<K,V> {
 K getKey();
 V getValue();
}
```

I am trying to modify chainhashmap to do the same behavior as hash map.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the problem is. [ask]

Comment: Do you mean a field to the next entry? Maybe something like:
`Entry<K,V> getNextEntry()`

Comment: I am developing a word frequency counter in the end and I have a reference "next" I am trying to modify in the above class to include a extra field for it.

Comment: How do you represent the reference? Is it a different class?

Comment: Yes, in the abstractmap class with line                                                       'public K next() { return entries.next().getKey(); }'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to ask, but this might be helpful.

```
public final class Pair<L, R> {

    private L left;
    private R right;

    public Pair() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public Pair(L initLeft, R initRight) {
        left = initLeft;
        right = initRight;
    }

    public synchronized L getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public synchronized R getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public synchronized void setLeft(L newLeft) {
        left = newLeft;
    }

    public synchronized void setRight(R newRight) {
        right = newRight;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        if (other instanceof Pair) {
            Pair<?, ?> otherPair = (Pair<?, ?>) other;
            return ((this.left == otherPair.left
                    || (this.left != null && otherPair.left != null && this.left.equals(otherPair.left)))
                    && (this.right == otherPair.right
                            || (this.right != null && otherPair.right != null && this.right.equals(otherPair.right))));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized String toString() {
        return "(" + left.toString() + "," + right.toString() + ")";
    }

}
```

You can use `Pair` as the value in the map entry with `left` as the actual value and `right` as the `next` value which u want